# Get position in class hierarchy

Tags: objective-c

Is the a way to get the number of ancestors for an instance of class?
E.g. a class of type UITouch would be of level 2 as it inherits from NSObject.

Comment: Is there a reason you need it? This smells like bad design to me.

Comment: :-)  I just want to use it for my log file - doing some printouts during dealloc and want indentations according to the classes inheritance level.

Answer (score 6):

```
int level = 1;
Class cls = [UITouch class];
while (cls = [cls superclass])
  ++ level;
return level;
```